# Angular 2+ project not accept external js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular5

Hello i bought a theme from themeforest. Its not angular 2+ theme.
Im trying to use theme in my angular project i almost read all document about include external js files in angular project i used a lot of strategy but didn't work

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="tr">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="keywords"
            content="Tercüme"/>
      <title>İlksen Tercüme</title>
      <base href="/">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/theme/fonts/flaticon.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/theme/css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/theme/css/responsive.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="preloader"></div>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <div class="scroll-to-top scroll-to-target" data-target="html"><span class="fa fa-angle-up"></span></div>

    <!-- THEME JAVASCRIPT FILES -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRvBPo3-t31YFk588DpMYS6EqKf-oGBSI"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/gmaps.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/map-helper.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/owl/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/nouislider/nouislider.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/bootstrap-touch-spin/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/isotope.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/masterslider/masterslider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/chartjs/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/jquery-circle-progress-1.1.2/dist/circle-progress.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/morris.js-master/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/raphael-master/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/Magnific-Popup-master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/assets/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/theme/js/custom.js"></script>
    <!-- // -->

    </body>

    </html>
```

this is my index.html file

also try these js files import from angular.cli file 
also try import these files from app.component.ts and call with constructor

anything helps nothing

but css files works great just js files problem

how can i solve this issue ?

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "my-new-project"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "./assets/styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "./assets/scripts.js",
        "./assets/theme/js/custom.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

angular cli file

scripts.js works but custom.js not working :(

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: no ı dont get any error

Comment: only ı get error if ı remove the scripts tags from index.html errors like 
$carousel is not a function